# Zend Controller all actions to one action

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-controller

I have categorie Controller, with index action

I need that when I enter address `.com/categorie/education`
it uses index action with parameter education `.com/categorie/index/education`

or redirect all actions to index ??

Comment: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/16/routing-and-complex-urls-in-zend-framework/ found better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are your routes setup? Given the lack of information provided I have to *assume* that you are using an .ini file, this is how it would work:

```
; CATEGORIE
categorie.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
categorie.route = "categorie"
categorie.defaults.controller = categorie
categorie.defaults.action = index

categorie_view.route = "categorie/:slug"
categorie_view.defaults.controller = category
categorie_view.defaults.action = view
```

Note, I did change it up a bit, as the index action, imo, should list all categories. This way you have a viewAction to list the individual categorie.

To have it as you requested I believe it would be something like:

```
; CATEGORIE
categorie.route = "categorie/:slug"
categorie.defaults.controller = categorie
categorie.defaults.action = index
```